# Cannot resolve Firebase symbols

Tags: android, firebase, android-gradle-plugin

I created a new Android Studio's bottom bar sample Project then I am trying to add firebase to my project.

I followed Firebase tools offered by Android Studio then I had a "cannot resolve symbol 'FirebaseStorage' error.

I red all Stack Overflow answer but the error persist.

My dependencies are:

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.3'
implementation 'com.firebase:firebase-client-android:2.5.2'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

At the bottom of my build.gradle (app) I have put:

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

the error is shown when I try to create a Storage Reference on my "onCreate" method and it's made for every Firebase tools I use (e.g. Firebase Auth)

```
    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
```

What I am missing?

Comment: Long shot but could you try chancing it with " com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.1.0 "

Comment: If I try your solution i get ERROR: The library com.google.android.gms:play-services-base is being requested by various other libraries at [[15.0.1,15.0.1]], but resolves to 16.0.1. Disable the plugin and check your dependencies tree using ./gradlew :app:dependencies.